# Assign empty function

Tags: swift, function

I have a function like this:

```
func doSomething(data: (() -> Void)?) {
    let data = data ?? { } // error
}
```

Why can't I assign `{ }` to data if `data` is `nil`?

> Binary operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type '(() -> Void)?' and '() -> Void'

```
func doSomething(data: (() -> Void)?) {
    var randomFunc = { }
    let data = data ?? randomFunc // this works
}
```

Comment: whats the error you get in the first case

Comment: I've quoted the error in my question.

Comment: it is very interesting, especially because if you change var randomFunc = {} to let randomFunc = {}, you receive the same error :-). key to the explanation could be the keyword @autoclosure. check http://en.swifter.tips/autoclosure/